# Компьютер не находится в suspend

Tags: linux, suspend

Вопникла проблема и чет даже не знаю куда копать.

перевожу компьютер в suspend - sudo pm-suspend
комп выключаетя, вентиляторы останавливаються и сразу опять запускаются.
не знаю куда копать, что может быть?

uname -a

Linux workstation55 4.15.0-64-generic #73-Ubuntu SMP Thu Sep 12 13:16:13 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

В какие логи посмотреть не понимаю.

Comment: google://ubuntu+awake+right+after+suspend

Comment: https://01.org/blogs/qwang59/2018/how-achieve-s0ix-states-linux